# Empty object minus/plus empty object, and reverse value

Tags: javascript

I have very simply question. Now in console I'm training some "arithmetics", like:

```
false + true // 1
```

So, the question is, why:

```
[] - {} // NaN
```

and

```
{} - [] // -0
```

Can anybody explain this, because both of them types is object. And I know that javascript have truly and falsy values. So, if we take

```
Boolean({}) // true
Boolean([]) // true
```

in both we have `true` and I think the result will be like:

```
true + true // 2
```

or

```
true - true // 0
```

Comment: `{} - []` should be `NaN`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek why? I think it should be 1

Comment: Because `+{}` is `NaN`. When I do `console.log({} - [])` the result is `NaN`, at least in Chrome.

Comment: This reminds me https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Answer (score 2):

In this context (in the console), {} is an empty block that does nothing, so the result is the same as

```
- []
```

And [] will coerce to 0, as seen by:

```
+[]
```

If you want {} to be treated as an empty object, try this:

```
({}) - []
```

You will get NaN now, since an empty object does not coerce to a number.

Update: This will also work as you should expect in the console (returning NaN):

```
({} - [])
```

Comment: The particular craziness here is why `+[]` coerces to `0`. The answer seems to be [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8) - if `Obj.valueOf()` does not return a primitive, then `Obj.toString()` is called, and *that* is the basis for numeric conversion. `[].toString() === ""` and `+"" === 0`. Also, this bizarrely means that `+[[["3.2"]]] === 3.2`. Ridiculous.

Comment: @nrabinowitz How would you convert an array to a number, otherwise? I think joining an array is the most reasonable way to convert it to a primitive, and then the unary `+` converts the string to a number.

Comment: @Oriol - well, I would have gone straight to `NaN`. But IANALD (I am not a language designer).

Comment: thanks a lot, I forgot to check their values. But your `({} - [])` don't work as i want. I want that {} + [] will be a 2. Can it be done?

Comment: {} at the beginning of a statement will always be parsed as a statement block, not an object literal, so no, it can not work.  ({} + []) can be made to work (at least in Chrome console) by overriding the toString methods of the Array and Object prototypes to (conditionally?) return 1.  However, that's not something anyone should do, ever.  Don't do it.